# Добавить строки из одного DataFrame в другой

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два датафрейма с одинаковыми названиями столбцов, но с разными данными:

```
var1    var2
Fger    EEE
ffs     ss
DEE     aq#
```

И второй:

```
var1    var2
1       1
2       2
```

Нужно просто добавить все строки в один датафрейм, то есть на выходе получить:

```
var1    var2
Fger    EEE
ffs     ss
DEE     aq#
1       1
2       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [pd.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
res = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

или [DataFrame.append(another)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
res = df1.append(df2)
```

PS `pd.concat()` выгоднее использовать для объединения 3+ фреймов

---

Примеры:

Исходные фреймы:

```
In [59]: df1
Out[59]:
   var1 var2
0  Fger  EEE
1   ffs   ss
2   DEE  aq#

In [60]: df2
Out[60]:
   var1  var2
0     1     1
1     2     2
```

---

```
In [61]: res = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

In [62]: res
Out[62]:
   var1 var2
0  Fger  EEE
1   ffs   ss
2   DEE  aq#
3     1    1
4     2    2
```

---

```
In [73]: res = df1.append(df2)

In [74]: res
Out[74]:
   var1 var2
0  Fger  EEE
1   ffs   ss
2   DEE  aq#
0     1    1
1     2    2
```